# parse error setting a variable in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I have a config class which gets used throughout my code. One variable within this class is the website URL. Recently, I added SSL to my server and now I need to check for this and assign either 'http' or 'https' as the protocol.

The code I tried is:

```
<?php

class Test
{
   public static $blah = (1 == 1) ? 'this' : 'or this';
}

echo Test::$blah;

?>
```

This produces a parse error.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you cannot set default class variables using expressions. You can only use primitive types and values. Only `array()` is recognized.

What you can do is create an "Static Initializer" function which can only be called once and will set your variables... As such:

```
<?php

class Test
{
   public static $blah;
   private static $__initialized = false;

   public static function __initStatic() {
       if(self::$__initialized) return;

       self::$blah = (1 == 1) ? 'this' : 'or this';

       self::$__initialized = true;
   }
}
Test::__initStatic();
```

And then simply fetch your variable from your other file:

```
<?php
echo Test::$blah;
```

If you edit `Test::$blah` later in the code, it will not be reverted by an accidental call to `Test::__initStatic()`.

Comment: +1 That's a really interesting design pattern / workaround for php.  Throwing a function call into a class file feels a little dirty, but it'll work,

Comment: @Chris Henry: sometimes you have to get yourself dirty when working with PHP. You definitely do not want to see my custom Error/Exception/RunTime_Err handling library.

Comment: A little off topic, but awhile ago my band recorded an album.  When we were mastering, the recordings weren't perfect.  The engineer told us "It's not rock n roll unless there's a little dirt on it".  PHP is no different.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a calculation to determine an object property value. You'll need to do this:

```
<?php

class Test
{
   public static $blah;
}

// set the value here
Test::$blah = (1 == 1) ? 'this' : 'or this';


echo Test::$blah;

?>
```